# Map fragment is black after resume

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have application that have on her main screen map (v2) with buttons. These buttons after click run another application and this (main activity) is in stack. After in that another activity is called `finish()`,main activity is back in front. But after this, map fragment is **black** and it's not working.

[image]

This is my fragment XML:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
    android:layout_width="100px"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

And the only thing I'm doing is `setContentView(R.layout.new_main);` and nothing more.

This problem is almost like mine: [Android MapView v2 Black screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603896/android-mapview-v2-black-screen), and also with no answer.

Comment: hey.. Did you got answer??

Comment: no, nothing yet... but this issue is known https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5767

Answer (score 5):

Please try with the code which is given below:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapFragment.onResume();
}
```

Comment: hmm... what if `mapFragment` is null?

Answer (score 3):

I Disable hardware acceleration at file manifest.xml, and my application doesnt show black map again in second load. i try it in emulator.

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
 ...
</application
```

from this article: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: First, If  your map is inside ScrollView, you will get black borders onScroll, Second, doesn't fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have exactly the same problem since a week.
When the mapfragment is destroy, it call onDestroyView()

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {

    super.onDestroyView();
    SupportMapFragment fragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    if (fragment != null)
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
}
```

When the mapFragment is going to appear again, it's this code :

```
private void showFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment == null)
        return;

    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    // We can also animate the changing of fragment
    ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

    ft.replace(R.id.address_displayer, fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    ft.commit();
}
```

The application doesn't crash but the map is black with still the zoom cursor and the icon for getting the current location of the device;

Perhaps important, i'm using the emulator.

Comment: For me it wasn't working on real device either. Now when I want to re-open activity with map it will be created as new. It's very bad solution but I didn't find any better. When You will find something, please write something about it... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mine was really stupid reason.
I removed `background` attribute from my `xml`.

```
android:background="@android:color/black"
```

PS. I used `FrameLayout` in `xml` for `SupportMapFragment`.