# Google map is unresponsive after resume application

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, onresume

I am working on Google map using api v2,i have added code to display map and it working,but i have two problems,
1.when map is displayed and then device is locked,then after unlocking device onResume() of fragment is called and map fragment is not responde(i can't scroll or zoom it).
2.I also have a button on same view,onClick of that button opens a mail intent.so application is paused,after that when user moves to application map fragment is black and map is not loaded.

i have try by seting `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` as  [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330589/map-fragment-is-black-after-resume) suggest,but it is not working for me.

my code inside oncreate is-

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
marker.position(myPosition);
marker.title(myTitle);
Marker locationMarker = map.addMarker(marker);
locationMarker.showInfoWindow();
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myPosition, 15));
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);
```

I ahve also try by removing child view using -

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
 if (parent != null)
     parent.removeView(v);
```

and also used below code in onResume() of my mapFragment -

```
SupportMapFragment fragments  = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
if(fragment!=null){
   FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
       ft.remove(fragments);
       ft.commit();
}
```

Please help me where i am missing.

Comment: are you initializing the map onResume?

Answer (score 0):

Make a private function,

```
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (map == null) {
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (map == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}
```

Comment: when onResume called map is not null and it display map because i have added onSavedInstanceState() method in my code,but map is not  respode.

Comment: after clearing map same problem,so i have tried map=null after map.clear() but result is same.